# I need help to make 3 Excel rules (explanation will follow) that highlight a row with Green/Yellow/Red depending on rule

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

First off, this is a spreadsheet that is intended to help me keep track of subject tasks that I have (for school).

I am proficient in Python, but this Excel formulas thing is new to me.

This is what what my spreadsheet looks like:

[image: Spreadsheet]

I want to have three rules in Excel, that highlight the rows as follows:

Highlight row with red; if:

- Date Due = Today

Highlight row with yellow; if:

- Date Due = This Week
- Done = False

Highlight row with green; if:

- Date Due = NOT This Week

OR

- Done = True
- Date Due = NOT Today

Could someone inform me of what these rules could look like, and how I should type them in the 'New Formatting Rule' box?

Thanks :)

Comment: Here is a non-related alternative you might want to consider.  Google Calendar or similar.   You can get email reminders at whatever intervals you want, and have multiple views include day, week,month, and if you want it in list form Agenda view.  It web based so you don't have to carry it around with you or risk losing it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use conditional formatting for it.

1. select your data
2. go to home / conditional formatting / new / select a formula ...

> Highlight row with red; if:
>
> - Date Due = Today

`=$D1=TODAY()`

> Highlight row with yellow; if:
>
> Date Due = This Week AND Done = False

`=AND(WEEKNUM(TODAY())=WEEKNUM($D1),$F1=FALSE)`

> Highlight row with green; if:
>
> Date Due = NOT This Week OR
>   Done = True AND Date Due = NOT Today

`=OR(WEEKNUM(TODAY())<>WEEKNUM($D1),AND($F1=TRUE,$D1<>TODAY()))`

Comment: The date index is wrong. It should be F not D according to the captions.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column with the following formula which is going to tell you which color the row should have:

`=IF(AND($H2="False", $F2=TODAY()), "RED", IF(AND($H2="False", WEEKNUM($F2)<WEEKNUM(TODAY()+7)), "Yellow", "Green"))`

It's essentially a switch case:

```
if(date == today AND done == false){ Red }  
else if(WEEKNUM(date) < WEEKNUM(today+7)){ Yellow }  
else{ Green }
```

After that you can follow this [HowToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/45670/how-to-highlight-a-row-in-excel-using-conditional-formatting/) article to color the rows. Essentially you setup three conditional coloring rules which use a formula akin to `$J1="Red"` and do use a range `$A:$J` to be applied to.

If you don't want to use the additional column just use the single test for your conditional formatting. So you'd get two conditional formats using each one of those formulas and setting the appropriate color:

```
=AND($H1="False", $F1=TODAY()) -- Color Red
=AND($H1="False", WEEKNUM($F1)<WEEKNUM(TODAY()+7) -- Color Yellow
```

The default color would be green. And be careful to use the index 1 for the column or they'll be offset.

P.S. `WEEKNUM` might not be optimal since it can to some funky things (different definitions of what the first full week of a year is) so there might be a better way to check this.